# Which MySQL version is my application using if I have both wamp as well as standalone MySQL installed separately?

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-services, version, wampserver

I have a windows app which has MySQL backend. I have `wampserver` installed on my machine which bundles a certain version of `phpmyadmin` along with MySQL version 5.0.51a. But in client machines they have MySQL version 5.1. In short development is on 5.0, while deployment is on 5.1. This is creating a bit of issues for us, since those two versions behave slightly different. So I got a standalone setup of vesion 5.1 and installed on my (development) machine.

Now when I run my app, it needs either wamp services (version 5.0) turned on, or it needs MySQL 5.1 (standalone installation installed in Program Files>MySQL>...) Both ways work.

Question1: Am I right to assume my app is relying on MySQL 5.0 if only wamp service is turned on and on MySQL 5.1 if only original MySQL service is turned on? Yes I suppose.

Question2 (main question): The app works if I have both services turned on aswell. In that case how can I know which MySQL version is my app running on? All I have is a connectionstring which looks like:

```
 MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=wow; 
                                           UID=root;PASSWORD=; Min Pool Size = 0; 
                                           Max Pool Size=200");
```

Tool runs on C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use `SELECT VERSION()`.  That will answer both of your questions.

Comment: @nawfal, yes, you can run it through C# with [`ExecuteScalar`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-executescalar).  Of course, it will work however you access MySQL.